# iOS Scatter core plot with a gap

Tags: ios, core-plot, scatter-plot

How does one draw a scatter plot with a gap using core plot? I was using the core plot library. Everything is working fine but now I want to do a scatter plot with a gap at the beginning or in the middle of the dataline? Someone help me please?

Comment: Hi James, was your question related to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259802/hide-alternate-lines-in-scatter-chart-coreplot?noredirect=1#comment54852022_33259802) ? Can you tell me if this is possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have the datasource return `nil` or `[NSNull null]`. For example, if the plot has five data points and you return `nil` for the x or y field at index 2, the plot will draw the points at indices 0 and 1 connected by a line and indices 3 and 4 connected by a line with a gap in between.

Comment: Hi Eric, are there any way to force the line to connect even when there is no data in between?

Comment: Data points don't have to be evenly spaced along the axis. If you don't want a gap, make sure you provide valid numbers for x and y at each index.

Comment: @EricSkroch i tried to return nil for invalid values but still by default it is setting to zero value... how can i give gap for invalid value...pleasehelp..Thanks in advance

Comment: @SteveGear Ask a new question with details of your situation and we can help.