# Issue with plotting broken graph in ios (core plot)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

i have been working with core plot to render various graph and successfully rendered some of graphs. Now I'm trying to achieve same as below image (i.e if there is no readings for some range on x axis, that portion should be kept blank instead of Zero or any other value), is there any chance with core plot?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked..
[iOS Scatter core plot with a gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333532/ios-scatter-core-plot-with-a-gap)

Actually i tried this before by returning nil and get crashed, But [NSNULL NULL] WORKED!