# How to achieve customizations in core plot -scatter plot?

Tags: ios, ipad, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am working on core Plot library in ios.I was able to add mutliple scatter plots to graph.I am not able to achieve following customizations(Pls refer attached image):

1. Need to connect multiple Y-axis points and draw a vertical line.
2. On X-axis,need to add number of tasks(Custom UI views) for every month.

[image]

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a third scatter plot to draw the vertical lines.
2. Don't add subviews to the Core Plot hosting view. Add them to the hosting view's superview. You can use the plot space to find the coordinates along the x-axis to anchor your custom views.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for your reply. I used a third scatter plot and was able to get the vertical line graph. But its a complete graph. What i need is just alternate vertical line. Please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259802/hide-alternate-lines-in-scatter-chart-coreplot   Please let me know if this is possible using core plot.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333532) for hints on how to skip values in a plot.