# Hide alternate lines in scatter chart coreplot

Tags: ios, core-plot, scatter-plot

Can we join alternate coordinates using line in coreplot -> scatter graph in ios ? 
[image]

In above picture suppose I want to join alternate points , what i mean is 
    {0,0} - {1,6} will be joined 
    {1,6} - {2,5} wont be joined 
    {2,5} - {3,6} joined and so on ...

Is this possible in coreplot ?
Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333532/ios-scatter-core-plot-with-a-gap

Comment: Thank you @EricSkroch It worked with the given way !