# ScatterPlot with gap -[NSNull doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I've been trying to create a gap in my scatterPlot using this suggestion:
[iOS Scatter core plot with a gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333532/ios-scatter-core-plot-with-a-gap)

I wanted to draw 2 vertical lines by creating the data:

```
NSMutableArray<NSDictionary *> *contentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [contentArray addObject:@{ @"x": _startPointValue, @"y": _startValue }];
        [contentArray addObject:@{ @"x": _startPointValue, @"y": @5 }];

        //add null points not to link the 2 lines
        [contentArray addObject:@{ @"x": _endPointValue, @"y": [NSNull null] }];
        [contentArray addObject:@{ @"x": _endPointValue, @"y": _endValue }];
        [contentArray addObject:@{ @"x": _endPointValue, @"y": @5 }];

        _verticalLinesData = contentArray;
```

but I receive error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a0f0e490'
```

When I comment out the line with [NSNull null], the lines are drawn properly (but connected).

What could be the reason. I don't use the _verticalLinesData elsewhere (only in coreplot's datasource methods).

EDIT:
my datasource methods:

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:VERTICALLINESPLOTID] ) {
        return _verticalLinesData.count;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

-(id)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSString *key = (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y");
    NSNumber *num = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
   if ([plot.identifier isEqual:VERTICALLINESPLOTID] ) {
        num = _verticalLinesData[index][key];
        num = @([num doubleValue]);
    }
    else {
        num = 0;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Where does that crash occur? Please post your datasource methods so we can see how the `_verticalLinesData` array is used.

Comment: Yup, according to question below I see I am trying to convert null->doubleValue. What should I deliver to coreplot then? Check if num is nil and return nil instead of calling this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the values from `_verticalLinesData` directly. Remove the line `num = @([num doubleValue]);` and it will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use '**[NSNull null]**' in dictionary key,value pair.

the crash occure when you attempt to convert this null value into double value

so you have 2 options

1. avoid to insert '**[NSNull null]**'. instead you can insert **@(-1)**;
   or
2. you can check null value when you are  double/float value